# Finding support for frequently occurring items

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a DataFrame where each row has order id and an item. I'd like to know which items appear most frequently with another (maybe probability of item appearing in order given that another item is there?)

Let's say the data is

```
order_id,item
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,a
2,b
2,d
3,a
3,b
3,e
```

Then the pair `a,b` gets the highest score.

(I'm sure there's a technical name for this, can't find it :)

One possible output will be probability of pair appearing in order, in our case something like:

```
item1,item2,probablility
a,b,1
a,b,0.3
b,c,0.3
a,d,0.3
b,c,0.3
a,e,0.3
b,3,0.3
```

Comment: so what is your expected output ?

Comment: Updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrive at co-occurrence matrix

First, get order, item combination of occurrences

```
In [249]: cross = pd.crosstab(df['order_id'], df['item'])

In [250]: cross
Out[250]:
item      a  b  c  d  e
order_id
1         1  1  1  0  0
2         1  1  0  1  0
3         1  1  0  0  1
```

Then, do product of cross and transposed cross.

```
In [251]: cross.T.dot(cross)
Out[251]:
item  a  b  c  d  e
item
a     3  3  1  1  1
b     3  3  1  1  1
c     1  1  1  0  0
d     1  1  0  1  0
e     1  1  0  0  1
```

This gives you co-occurrences of every item with every other item based on order_id.

Comment: Thanks. To get probability I just need to divide `Out[251]` by `df['order_id'].nunique()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to calculate the support for various subsets of items. I have written a general code which finds the support for all combinations.

#### Creating the dataset

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
data = StringIO("""order_id,item
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,a
2,b
2,d
3,a
3,b
3,e""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

#### Cross-tabulating

```
e = pd.crosstab(index=df.order_id, columns=df.item)
e = e.astype('bool')
```

This is how `e` looks

```
item    a   b   c   d   e
order_id                    
1   True    True    True    False   False
2   True    True    False   True    False
3   True    True    False   False   True
```

Now, for all combinations of subsets of lengths varying from 1 to number of unique items, we query if all the items in the subset have a True.

#### Main logic

```
from itertools import combinations
out = {}
for k  in range(1, len(df.item.unique())):
    combination_len_k = list(combinations(df.item.unique(), k))
    for c in combination_len_k:
        q = " & ".join(list(c))
        out[c] = len(e.query(q))*1./len(e)
```

This gives us the following result.

```
{('a',): 1.0,
 ('a', 'b'): 1.0,
 ('a', 'b', 'c'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): 0.0,
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('a', 'b', 'd'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('a', 'b', 'e'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('a', 'c'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('a', 'c', 'd'): 0.0,
 ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('a', 'c', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('a', 'd'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('a', 'd', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('a', 'e'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('b',): 1.0,
 ('b', 'c'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('b', 'c', 'd'): 0.0,
 ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('b', 'c', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('b', 'd'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('b', 'd', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('b', 'e'): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('c',): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('c', 'd'): 0.0,
 ('c', 'd', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('c', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('d',): 0.3333333333333333,
 ('d', 'e'): 0.0,
 ('e',): 0.3333333333333333}
```

#### Printing only length 2 combinations

In case you want to print only the length two combinations, you can modify `for k  in range(1, len(df.item.unique())):` and remove the loop by setting `k=2`. The answer in that case will be:

```
pd.Series(out)

a  b    1.000000
   c    0.333333
   d    0.333333
   e    0.333333
b  c    0.333333
   d    0.333333
   e    0.333333
c  d    0.000000
   e    0.000000
d  e    0.000000
```